# Cocos2d js, как сделать подобное?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d

Сначала нужно нарисовать что-то типа шахматной доски(то есть квадрат состоящий из белых и черных ячеек)
Потом заполнить это рандомными фишками разных цветов.
Создаю прямоугольник

```
let rectField = new cc.DrawNode();
rectField.drawRect(cc.p(20, 50), cc.p(310, 558), cc.color(128, 128, 128), cc.color(128, 128, 128));
this.addChild(rectField);
```

Но как разделить его ячейки не понимаю, с помощью каких инструментов это можно сделать.
Как я понимаю нужно создать контейнер, потом по нему проходится и рисовать каждую ячейку. Может знаете примеры подобного ?

Comment: Приведи пример того, что сам сделал и что именно не получается...

Comment: Обновил вопрос .